# Error reparing mongo db

Tags: mongodb, database

I have one mongo 3.0.2 database on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
Size of data directory - 3.5 TB.
Database worked during several days with failed RAM hardware.
Now RAM is replaced with good one, but database does not work well - server crushes or requests are processed forever. I do not have backups of database.

I tried to repare db:
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /storage/mongodb/data/ --repair

-- worked a couple of days and failed with error:
Assertion: 13440:bad offset:-1855130448 accessing file: /storage/mongodb/data/proxycache.82

- Is it possible to fix this database somehow or I need to report lost data?
- How to backup such a database in the future, if creating tar file without compression takes more than one day for such a huge db?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [Official MongoDB Repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md), the 13440 error code usually indicates data corruption which, in your case, might be due to an unexpected shutdown.

What you can do right now is go through this [section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) from the official documentation and see if you can find any solution to recovering your data accordingly.

Comment: I used commands from section, you mentioned. It proposes to use command, I typed in question: mongod --dbpath /storage/mongodb/data/ --repair  
And it gives the error while repair.

Comment: Have you tried running it with the --repairPath as well to write the data to new data files? Afterwards, you would have to change the dbpath to the new location.